# Double figure reference Apacite

Tags: citing

I am trying to cite to 2 figures within specific papers with apacite. I figured out how to cite 1 figure in one paper:

```
\cite[Fig. 1]{paper1}
```

But I can not seem to figure out how to combine 2 citations such as that it will look like:

```
(Paper 1, Fig. 1; Paper 2, Fig 1)
```

I've tried a couple of options including:

```
\cite[Fig. 1]{paper1}[Fig. 1]{paper2} and 
\cite[Fig. 1][Fig.1]{paper1}{paper2}
```

but those do not seem to work. Anyone who has an idea?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the same `\cite` call? I would just do `(\cite[x]{paper1}; \cite[y]{paper2})`.

Comment: I have tried it with two different commands, but then the result is as follows:

input: (\cite[Fig.1]{Paper1}; \cite[Fig.1]{Paper2})
output: (Paper 1 (2000, Fig. 1); Paper2 (2001, Fig. 1))

whereas I am trying to get the result:
(Paper 1, 2000, Fig. 1; Paper 2, 2001, Fig. 1)

Comment: Ok, I think you might need to use a different command then. Which one would depend for example on if you're using `bibtex` or `biblatex`, and what citation style you have chosen.

Comment: I have solved it for now by just typing in text what I wanted, and included the references in my reference list by using /nocite